# Excel test for job application

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have recently tried to solve an excel test, but I got stuck at one point where I need to calculate totals for different hours.

For example, I have different times 09:01, 09:32, 09:59 and so on...

I need to calculate clicks on emails per hour in order to get the hourly performance.

I was using the =SUMIFS(N:N;E:E;">=09:00") formula, but I am not sure what the **Criteria1** should be in order to get the total number of clicks for one hour (from 09:00-09:59).

What should I put in Criteria 1 so I can calculate the hourly performance?

Please pay attention to  columns E and N. I have different times at E and i have made a sum to emails sent opened and clicked.

Now I have to calculate per hour 01-24 all the emails that were sent opened and clicked. I have tried with the formula you gave me but it simply won't work.

I am trying to connect N and E columns with COUNTIF but it always gives me a result 0, which is not correct.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Can you edit your post and include a screenshot of the data? The solution to this problem will depend on the format of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that if you want to calculate how often things were clicked and the time values are time stamps for each click, then you want to Count, not Sum.

If the time value in the cell is a real time value, i.e. one that changes do a decimal number with a zero before the decimal divider when you format it as "General", then you can use something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=9:00",A:A,"<10:00")
```

You want to make sure that the time values are formatted with custom format `h:mm` and not with AM/PM.

If the value contains a date as well, i.e. a number before the decimal divider in General format, then you need a different approach. In that case you need to look only at the hour part of the date/time and determine its value. To do that you can use SumProduct, but do NOT use that with whole columns. You need to ringfence the row numbers, otherwise the spreadsheet will recalculate very slowly.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(A2:A1000)=9))
```

**Edit after more details**
Based on your screenshot, it looks like you want to add the numbers in column N for only the rows where the time is between 9 and 10 am. The formula you posted has only one condition for greater than 9 am, but it does not restrict the hours to less than 10 am. For that you need:

```
=SUMIFS(N:N,E:E,">=09:00",E:E,"<10:00")
```

If you cannot get that formula to work, then there are two possibilities:

- the data that looks like time values in column E is not really time values, but text. To check this, try to change the format of a single cell in that column to "General". If the time value changes to a decimal number, then the cell has a real time value. If the format does not change, the cell has text and you need to change the text to a real time value before the formula can work.
- if the cell has real time values and the formula still does not work, then take a look at the separators between the formula parameters. You have posted a formula that has semicolons. Does your system really use semicolons in formulas? This is determined by regional settings of your computer. Some countries use the comma (US, Australia), other regions use the semicolon (Europe). If you use the wrong symbol, Excel won't even let you enter the formula, so that should be very easy to test.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work, please see the question again i have added a picture with more details. Thank you.

Comment: I added a formula and screenshot to my answer,

Comment: Thank you very very much Teylyn, the last formula and the semicolons helped me a lot. The only struggle I had was that I could not double-click for auto-fill but i did it manually for all 24 hours.